# How to implement an abstract method when abstract class is used in a variadic context

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, pure-virtual

How to implement in the following code the abstract base class in a generic case. The code is simplified from a library I am working on. So an explicit implementation for int and double is not an option.

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
  virtual void send(T t) = 0;
};

template <typename...T>
struct Bar : Foo<T>...
{
  void send(T t) override { // does not compile because 
                            // abstract method not implemented
  }
};

int main() {
  // example usage
  Bar<int, double> b;

  b.send(1);
  b.send(2.3);
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit**: Added virtual to abstract method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about the following example?

First of all, I think you need define `virtual` the `send()` method in `Foo` (if you want it pure virtual).

Next, you can declare a intermediate template class (`Foo2`) where implement the `override` `send()`

Last, you can use a template `send()` method in `Bar` to select the correct virtual `send()` method.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Foo
 { virtual void send(T t) = 0; };

template <typename T>
struct Foo2 : Foo<T>
 {
   void  send(T) override
    { std::cout << "sizeof[" << sizeof(T) << "] " << std::endl; }
 };

template <typename...T>
struct Bar : Foo2<T>...
 {
   template <typename U>
   void send (U u)
    { Foo2<U>::send(u); }
 };

int main()
 {
   Bar<int, double> b;

   b.send(1);    // print sizeof[4]
   b.send(2.3);  // print sizeof[8]
 }
```

Comment: Hey, can you tell me what the difference is between:  `Foo2<T>...` and `Foo2<T...>`  (dots outside bracket vs. inside bracket)

Comment: @Brandon - are completely different things; if you write `Foo2<T...>`, you declare a single base class, `Foo2<T0, T1, T2 /* etc*/>`, with `sizeof...(T)` template parameters; if you write `Foo2<T>...`, you declare `sizeof...(T)` base classes, `Foo2<T0>, Foo2<T1>, Foo2<T2> /* etc */`, with a single template parameter each